# Vectorize function calls on each element of a vector

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, vectorization

When we call a function for each element in a vector using for_each are the calls vectorized or not?

Comment: What exactly is a vectorized call? Are you asking if `for_each` uses multiple threads?

Comment: Are you referring to SIMD instructions?

Comment: For example I am incrementing the elements by 5 in a function

Comment: Experimentally, the answer is "maybe". So it cannot be answered in general. If it was "no, never", that would have been an answer, but in some cases some compilers will do it ([proof](http://goo.gl/6JVihX)).

Answer (score 2):

In general, no.

`std::for_each` is simply a wrapper around a loop.

However, with optimizations on, it's quite likely that the call to `std::for_each` is inlined, and for simple functions, likely that the function call for each element is inlined too.

Once everything is inlined, it's as if the loop had been written by hand; in such a case, the question becomes "will the compiler vectorize a loop doing simple arithmetic"; and that's entirely up to the compiler.

In order for this to happen, the compiler needs to know that the target architecture supports SIMD instructions, and may or may not vectorize depending on the optimization level, whether the number of iterations is constant or not, whether the number of iterations is known to be a multiple of 4, etc.

Comment: To further generalize: if function call is not inlined, it's still possible to vectorize such loops by using #pragma omp declare simd on function declaration - which is also known as "SIMD enabled function" technique. Unfortunately this technique does only work in some versions of Intel compiler or in compilers supporting standard of OpenMP4.0.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you are asking about std::vector, the answer is no. std::vector is a wrapper around a array, but it accesses those memory blocks indirectly. However you can take the row pointer like so `myVec.begin()._Ptr` and work with it inside the loop. declaring method with noalias helps, like so `__declspec(noalias)`. The second part of the question is answered by Cameron. If the function gets inlined and architecture supports vectorized data, compiler should vectorize the data now.

Comment: All of this is completely platform-specific. And unncessary. You can just do `&myVec[0]`, which is guaranteed to work.